# Password keeper for iPhone, Mac and Windows?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

Are there any (preferably free/cheap) solutions for syncing and accessing encrypted passwords on a Mac, a PC and an iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://lastpass.com

Runs on virtually anything, and has awesome security. Not the prettiest, but the best features for the price.

Comment: Sounds great! This might very well be the way to go for me.

Comment: Awesome security is right.  Steve Gibson did a security review of it in Security Now episode 256 ( http://twit.tv/sn256 ).  Full synchronization and off-line capabilities too.  One time passwords, two factor authentications, etc.

Comment: The iPhone lastpass is paid $1 month. MyKeePass is $1 once.

Comment: @Anton They don't seem to be quite comparable feature-wise, and you can use the free Lastpass bookmarklet, which covers 99% of what I want to use it for.

Answer (score 12):

## [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password)

It's great and syncs on the iOS platform, and has a beta for Windows too now. :)

Comment: I use 1Password on OS X, Windows and iPhone, all synced together via Dropbox and it works great!

Comment: Sounds lovely, but with buying separate licenses for a Mac, a PC and the iPhone it gets fairly expensive. I'll keep it in mind, though!

Comment: It is truly amazing though. It's well worth the money for the app. :)

Answer (score 3):

I use [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/), which does the job, although it isn't as polished as 1Password the price is right. It does also work pretty well storing the file in DropBox and accessing the same file from KeePass for windows.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an iPhone app which can read/edit the same password data file? I'm already using Password Safe/Password Gorilla with Dropbox to sync between my Macs and PCs, but I haven't found an iPhone app to interact with them.

Comment: There is, called iKeepass, but it's currently only available in the US and Canada. I'm in the UK so can't try it, so have no idea if it's any good. It does seem to work with DropBox (http://ikeepass.de/bl0g/?p=175)

Comment: I use MyKeePass on iPhone, works also with dropbox. Make sure the number of times your database.kdb is encrypted is high enough.

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://supergenpass.com/, it's a bit different than the other solutions but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [PasswordWallet](http://www.selznick.com/products/passwordwallet/) to synchronize my Mac with my mobile device -- first a Palm Pilot, then the Treo, now the iPhone.  Very nice, I couldn't manage without it.

Comment: I saw something about it syncing via MobileMe, is that the only way to sync it?

Comment: @Lizzan:  Nope, I sync to my Mac without that.  Requires opening up desktop app & phone app at once and asking both to synchronize, and having the firewall on your Mac let PasswordWallet talk to the outside world.  (Since it only does that when you're explicitly trying to synchronize, I think it's safe enough.)